# How to go to next and previous object in JSON array returned by json_encode with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I'm currently trying to load some JSON image data from a PHP file with AJAX, and with jQuery cycle through the results on the click of a next/previous button. I can successfully load the data when I indicate a specified index (data.record[0].image;) but I want it to load the first index and nothing else, and go to the next JSON.object.image key/value pair ON CLICK, but I can't seem to get the next previous buttons to work. Here's what I have so far..

PHP:

```
    include('./connection.php');
    $query = "SELECT artist, title, year, image, description, ID FROM voting";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    if (!$result) die($mysqli->error);
    $array = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $array[] = $row;

    }
    echo json_encode(array('records' => $array), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

JSON is in the following format:

```
{"records":[
            {
                "artist":"At The Drive In",
                "title":"Acrobatic Tenement ",
                "year":"1996",
                "image":"./img/atdi01.jpg",
                "description":"Arguably the the pioneering album of post-hardcore, Acrobatic Tenement is At The Drive In's seminal album. ",
                "ID":"1"
            }
    ]
```

script.js file:

```
      $("#get-data").click(function(){ //load JSON data...
        $.getJSON("api.php", //gets a JSON data from api.php
          function(data){     //callback function if request succeeds


            $.each(data.records, function(i,record){
              var current = 0;
              var img = $("<img/>").attr({
                id: "album_image", 
                class: "album", 
                src: data.records[i].image,
                });
              $("#content").html(img);
              $("#next-bt").click(function(){
                current + 1;
                return false;
              });
              $("#prev-bt").click(function(){
                current - 1;
                return false;
              });

            });
          });           //end of callback function and end of .getJSON statement
      });               //end of button.click function
```

Please help! I'm about to pull my hair out.

Comment: It should be a Javascript Object, treat it like any other javascript object. _HINT:_ Look at it with your browsers js debugger

Comment: `src: record.image`

Comment: If you want the first index, why are you looping over it with `$.each`? You probably want to access `data.records[current]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is not needed. In your Ajax handler move your data to a global data variable. Then call `render()`. Try something like this:

```
var records;
var current = 0;

$("#next-bt").click(next);
$("#prev-bt").click(prev);

$("#get-data").click(function(){ //load JSON data...
   $.getJSON("api.php", //gets a JSON data from api.php
      function(data){     //callback function if request succeeds
          var records = data.records;
          render();
   }); //end of callback function and end of .getJSON statement
 });
function render(){
    var img = $("<img/>").attr({
          id: "album_image", 
           class: "album", 
           src: records[current].image,
     });
    $("#content").html(img);
}
function next(){
    current++;
    render();
}
function prev(){
   current--;
   render();
}
```

Disclaimer: There should be error checking in this code to ensure we can't go past the boundaries of the array.

Comment: I'm getting undefined for the src attribute in the img.. is it because the records variable is only set to data.records in the .getJSON function?

Comment: `records` should be holding an array of objects. Each object in the array should represent an album with artist, title, etc. The image should be one of those. So `records[current].image` should give you the property value. What do you get when you console.log(records[current].image) or debug that line of code?

Comment: I figured it out, it's because the global variable records wasn't being changed within the .getJSON. Thank you!